Is there a way to add observed factor scores from an IRT to the original dataframe
I have five Likert scale items that I conducted a unidimensional IRT on (GRM) in R. I obtained factor scores using the following command
scores <- factor.scores(fit2act, method = "EAP")

The output is shown below.
Output
I understand that this means that 197 have the same response pattern (all 1s) and should have the same parameter z1 (-2.41). However, I am having trouble appending these z1 estimates to my original dataframe because of the following error:
"Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, theta, value = list(act_hands = c(1,  :
replacement has 1884 rows, data has 13542"

I would like to know if there is a way to get the individual z1 estimates that I can append to my original dataframe for analysis? Is there a way to do this in R?

If you use dplyr::left_join(data, scores), assuming you don't have variables in your data named Obs, Exp, z1 or se.z1, that should do the trick.

What is IRT and GRM?
